# Google Datastore fetch entities for list of keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have an array of datastore keys. Is there a way to efficiently fetch the entities that correspond to these keys without running a query for every key in the element? Is there an IN_ARRAY operator or something? (I'm using the python API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`get_multi`](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/client.html#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client.get_multi) function to fetch a list of entities from keys.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware whether there is an "IN" operator or something like that tho?

Comment: While the "IN" operator is reserved in GQL (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference), the doc also states "Notice that the operator = is another name for the IN and CONTAINS operators. For example, <value> = <property-name> is the same as <value> IN <property-name>".